# Combinatorial expression for a sum for a complete graph

Tags: combinatorics

**EDIT:**
Consider a complete graph $G(V,E)$. Let each vertex have a spin $-1$ or $+1$. So $\{-1,+1\}^n$ is the space of all spin configurations. Let $x\in \{-1,+1\}^n$ and let $x_i$ denote the $i^{\rm th}$ vertex of $x$.

> I am trying to find an expression for $S:=\sum_{x\in \{-1,+1\}^n} \sum_{(i,j)\in E} x_ix_j$.

If $x=[+1,+1,\ldots,+1]$, then the contribution of this $x$ to $S$ is $n(n-1)/2$. If $x$ has one negative one and all other vertices being positive ones (there are $n$ such $x$ possible), then the contribution of such an $x$ to $S$ is $\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2}-(n-1)$. So

$$S=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}+n\cdot \left[ \frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2}-(n-1)\right]+\ldots$$

But I'd like an expression for $S$ where I know all the $c_j$ where $c_j$ is as follows:

$$S=\sum_{j=0}^n c_j$$

where $j$ stands for number of $+1$ in $x$ and $c_j$ stands for the summand of $S$ corresponding to that $j$.

Comment: Do you mean
$$S = \sum_{x \in \{\pm 1\}^n} \sum_{(i,j) \in E} x_i x_j \ ?$$
It seems like you want $(+1,\ldots,+1)$ to contribute $\sum_{e \in E} 1 = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$, but as it stands the sum does not make sense.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Yes, what you have written is correct, I forgot the other summation sign. I will edit the question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @HallaSurvivor suggest, you search for $$S = \sum_{x\in \{0, 1\}^n}S(x)$$ with  $$S(x) = \sum_{1\leq i< j \leq n} x_i x_j$$.

Let $E^+$ and $E^-$ be set of $x$ elements with sign $+$ or $-$. Let $n^+ = |E^+|$ and $n^- = |E^-|$.

We have $$S_{n^+} = S(x) = \sum_{x_i, x_j \in E^+, i< j}x_ix_j + \sum_{x_i, x_j \in E^-, i< j}x_ix_j +\sum_{x \in E^+, y \in E^-}xy\\
= \sum_{x_i, x_j \in E^+, i< j}1 + \sum_{x_i, x_j \in E^-, i< j}1 +\sum_{x \in E^+, y \in E^-}-1\\
= \frac{n^+(n^+-1)}{2} + \frac{n^-(n^--1)}{2} - n^+n^-$$

Then we have $$S = \sum_{x\in \{0, 1\}^n}S(x)= \sum_{n^+=0}^n \binom{n}{n^+} S_{n^+} = \sum_{n^+=0}^n\binom{n}{n^+}\left[\frac{n^+(n^+-1)}{2} + \frac{(n^-(n^--1)}{2} - n^+n^-\right]$$
With $n^- = n - n^+$.

We know that $$\sum_{k = 0}^n \binom{n}{k}\frac{k(k-1)}{2} = 2^n\frac{n(n-1)}{8}$$
Moreover, $$\sum_{k = 0}^n \binom{n}{n-k}\frac{(n-k)(n-k-1)}{2} = \sum_{k = 0}^n \binom{n}{k}\frac{k(k-1)}{2} = 2^n\frac{n(n-1)}{8} $$
We also know that $$\sum_{k = 0}^n \binom{n}{k}k(n-k) =  2^n\frac{n(n-1)}{4}$$
So $$S = 0$$
Was this predictable?
For each $1\leq i < j \leq n$, $x_ix_j$ take the sign $+$ as much as the sign $-$ (because once $x_i$ is fixed, the sign of $x_ix_j$ depends only on if $x_j$ is of the same sign of $x_i$, which happens in half of the $x$ vectors).

Comment: @RobPratt corrected